# Rhino: Retrieving the Line No and Column No

Tags: rhino

I am running my own proxy objects which extend org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.
I also have my own functions which extend org.mozilla.javascript.Function.

My desire is to have any exceptions thrown here return the line no and if possible the column number where they occurred in the evaluated script.  Is this possible?  I only have access to the context and the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an exception is thrown from a script, Rhino throws RhinoException which already has line and column number (and more). However when you execute the script you need to provide the line number that will be used by Rhino as the starting line number. The actual line number of where the exception/error occurred will be relative to this number. So something line this:

```
//-- Define a simple test script to test if things are working or not.
String testScript = "function simpleJavascriptFunction() {" +
                    "  this line has syntax error." +
                    "}" +
                    "simpleJavascriptFunction();";
//-- Compile the test script.
Script compiledScript = Context.getCurrentContext().compileString(testScript, "My Test Script", 2, null);
//-- Execute the test script.
compiledScript.exec(Context.getCurrentContext(), anyJavascriptScope);
```

In the above code, the starting line number is set to 2 (third parameter of the call to compileString()). When this is executed, Rhino will throw a RhinoException that will have the lineNumber property set to the value '3' (the first line is treated as the second line b/c we passed 2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: In truth, I think what I am after is impossible.  Im not actually calling a script, but rather rhino is calling a function on my object